# What should I do about unjustly closed questions?

Tags: discussion, flags, closed-questions

When I browse through Stack Overflow, I sometimes see closed questions which shouldn't be closed in my opinion. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405736/is-there-a-c-sharp-string-format-equivalent-in-javascript) is closed. I flagged it as "in need of moderator intervention" because it was "not a duplicate, the other one asks for jQuery, this is for Javascript." A moderator declined this, the reason is "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention."

Another example, I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652554/calling-java-from-python) ("Why is this off-topic?") because the question was about the ways to call Java from Python. It was again declined with the same reason above. But I also flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650263/visual-studio-2013-mstest-vs-nunit) as off-topic and it was declined without a reason.

I flagged two closed questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762905/how-can-i-display-a-list-view-in-an-android-alert-dialog), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268455/how-to-make-an-alert-dialog-with-a-spinner)) with very similar structure. One flag was "helpful" and the question was re-opened. The other one was declined and the reason was "People tend to react poorly to "write my code for me" questions. Maybe you could edit this to improve it, upon which time it will be reviewed for reopening by the community."

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074724/c11-full-support-on-eclipse) is not about tool recommendation but it is closed as if it were. My flag was declined.

Should I continue flagging unjustly closed questions? Are they not unjustly closed?

Comment: As this question is about a situation on *one specific site* in the Stack Exchange network, unfortunately, we have to mark this question as "off-topic" for this site. Each site has a *per-site meta* where you can ask questions about that site, which can be accessed through the site switcher on the top right corner. Questions on this site, Meta Stack Exchange, are expected to relate to the entire SE network as a whole, not just one specific site.

Answer (score 11):

> I flagged it as "in need of moderator intervention" because it was "not a duplicate, the other one asks for jQuery, this is for Javascript."

If you pay close attention to the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038746/equivalent-of-string-format-in-jquery), you'll see that the top answers don't use jQuery at all, it's just [vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/). So it's rightfully closed as a duplicate, it's just that the title of the original is a little misleading.

The problem with your flag is that opening/closing questions can/will be handled by the community, not by the ♦ moderators. There are simply too many questions and too few moderators ([new ones are coming, though](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380600/4751173)) for this to be feasible. If you want a question to be reopened, you need to cast a reopen vote – for which you need [3000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). A custom moderator flag, like you did, might work on smaller sites but on a site with the volume of Stack Overflow, it will simply be declined.

Note that for closing questions, you can use regular flags, which will be handled by the community (more specifically: regular users with 3000 or more reputation). There is no corresponding reopen flag, but an edit to a recently closed post (less than 5 days ago) will also put the question in the Reopen Votes review queue. And with only [250 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes), you can flag your *own* questions to be reopened (or closed).

> "Why is this off-topic?"

The concept of on-topic/off-topic might take a while to get used to. After all, it's a question about programming, right? It might help to think in terms of 'in scope'/'out of scope'; some types of questions are simply not a good fit for the Q&A format used by Stack Exchange. Off-topic reasons help to define the scope of a site, so that only the 'best' questions remain.

Comment: You should check the post timeline to make sure that it hasn't already been reviewed for reopening, because if it has, it won't be re-reviewed if it's edited.

Comment: True; there are some other cases as well (IIRC if the OP has closed it as a duplicate themselves). I'm not sure how often these happen and I didn't have time to find the post where these conditions are listed yet.

Comment: Also, you can make a meta post if you think a specific post should be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't have enough reputation to cast close & reopen votes (3k on graduated sites), there's not a whole lot you can do. Maybe leave a comment explaining the situation so someone with enough reputation might see the comment and possibly vote to reopen.

When you *do* have the necessary reputation, you can vote to reopen. It takes 5 votes to reopen a closed question, after which it will accept answers as normal.

You should *not* submit a custom moderator flag asking for it to be reopened. Moderators are "human exception handlers", and unless there's something really out of the ordinary going on (abuse, targeted close-voting, etc), they'll usually leave the question closed and decline your flag, as they did in your situation.